# Two separate joins on the same query

Tags: mysql

I have a query to find duplicates in a table:

```
SELECT sofferenze.id_soff, sofferenze.Descrizione
FROM sofferenze
INNER JOIN (
SELECT Descrizione
FROM sofferenze
GROUP BY Descrizione
HAVING count( id ) >1
)dup ON sofferenze.Descrizione = dup.Descrizione
ORDER BY Descrizione ASC
```

It works like a charm and gives me all the duplicated rows. 
I also have another query that starting from sofferenze.id_soff will give me another value in another table:

```
SELECT cod_fisc
FROM anagrafiche
JOIN `rischiatura` ON anagrafiche.id_ndg = rischiatura.id_ndg
WHERE id_ogg = 'SF000000012'
AND id_ruolo = 'RU010000002'
```

Actually this second query is run for each row returned by the first query replacing in this line `WHERE id_ogg='SF000000012'` the value 'SF000000012' with the value sofferenze.id_soff that is returned by the first query.

This code is not efficient because it runs several times the second query. 
Are there any option that I can merge the two queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not combine it into a sub-query?

```
SELECT cod_fisc
FROM anagrafiche
JOIN `rischiatura` ON anagrafiche.id_ndg = rischiatura.id_ndg
WHERE id_ogg IN (SELECT x.id_soff
    FROM sofferenze x
    WHERE x.Descrizione IN (
        SELECT ix.Descrizione
        FROM sofferenze ix
        GROUP BY ix.Descrizione
        HAVING count( * ) >1
    ))
AND id_ruolo = 'RU010000002'
```

Comment: I thought about that too but I am not very fond of subqueries. Usually are resource eaters. And this one is doing the same. It runs much slowlier than my actual set up.

Comment: @LelioFaieta Agreed. Sub-queries are generally a terrible idea; I thought this was a one-off process you were doing. I'll see if I can come up with something else.

Comment: It is part of a daily report to check data consistency in a financial application... so performance is a key indicator!! :) thanks for the help